# header("location: ..."); no redirecting as of new PHP update

Tags: php, header

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){
header("Location: ../welcome/index.php");
```

My login script seems to have stopped working recently, with the new update of PHP on July 19th.

Can anyone give a fix for this?

Here's the whole script.

---

```
<?
    include_once ('includes.inc.php');


    if (!isset($_POST['login']) || (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['password']) < 3)) { //User forgot a field
        header("Location: ../index.php?message=4");
    }
    else {
        $username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])), ENT_QUOTES);
        $password = sha1(trim($_POST['password']));
        $sqlPass  = mysql_query("SELECT isbanned, password, id FROM members WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
        $sqlPass  = mysql_fetch_array($sqlPass);


        if (($sqlPass['password'] == NULL) || ($sqlPass['password'] != $password)) { //User entered wrong information
            header("Location: ../index.php?message=5");
        }
        else if ($sqlPass['isbanned'] == '1') {
            header("Location: ../index.php?message=50");
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['uid']      = $sqlPass['id'];

            //Log IP
            AddIPToLogs();


            if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
                header("Location: ../welcome/index.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Cool, did my best. But, anyway I could get some help with this one?

Comment: Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is there any output being sent to browser before the header call? even a white space will cause header function to fail. Please also check includes.inc.php if it has any blank space or line outside the php block or if it echoes anything, most of the times that is the reason. session_start also needs to be called before you check for any values in $_SESSION array

Comment: Unfortunately, "stopped working" is not a valid PHP error. Please provide all relevant output, what you've tried, what you think it is, any missing code (*I seen an `include` happening there*) where the issue may be hiding, and any other pertinent details.

Comment: full url for header location is required, and exit() afterwards is best practice.

Comment: There are no output errors. I am an experienced PHP programmer, so I know the flaws with mysql_* statements. During login (use xtremerewards.net, login xtest/xtest2 ) it will refresh the index, but the login file isn't working with the header location call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 2):

Try `<?php` as a start tag instead of `<?`

or have you used session_start()??

or have you sent the header anywhere before?

is there any error that php show?

Comment: `<?php` should fix your problem!

Comment: I think so, but there was not too much spcification abut the problem.

Comment: The code was fully working before the PHP update, so it's an issue with such.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought, looking at the code provided, is that your if statement has a syntax error.

```
if (!isset($_POST['login']) || (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['password']) < 3)) { //User forgot a field
    header("Location: ../index.php?message=4");
}
```

should be

```
if ((!isset($_POST['login']) || (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['password']) < 3)) { //User forgot a field
    header("Location: ../index.php?message=4");
}
```

Also, you have an 'include' statement before your 'header('Location: ')' statement. An issue may exist within the code that you are including.

lastly, you should give specifics on how you updated your system, from which version of php to what 'latest' version. Did you do this update yourself, or are you running on a web hosted server?